# SSRS and accessing C# methods

Tags: c#-2.0, reportingservices-2005

Would like to know if methods need to be static in a C# assemble to be access from SSRS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, **you can use both public methods and static methods in a c# class library** and reference them from your SSRS report.

You do need to add static methods in a different way than your public instance methods though. You should check out this [MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769) on custom code use in SSRS. Here is the gist of how to add a static method:

> The Classes section is only for
> instance-based members. It is not for
> static members. Static (also referred
> to as "shared" in some of our
> Reporting Services documentation)
> means that the member is available to
> every instance of the class and every
> instance uses the same storage
> location. Static members are declared
> by using the shared keyword in
> Microsoft Visual Basic and the static
> keyword in C#. This can be a bit
> confusing. What this means is, if your
> custom assembly contains instance
> members that you need to access, you
> will have to specify the class name
> and instance name in the Classes
> section. Because the method I will be
> calling from Reporting Services was
> defined as static by using the shared
> keyword in Visual Basic, I'll use the
> References section instead of the
> Classes section.

So, if you want to do an instance method, make sure to add the refrence, but also specify a **"Class"** and **"Instance name"** in the Classes section of Report Properties for every method you need. Then call them using an expression of =Code. Like so:

```
=Code.InstanceName.Method
```

Hope that will help you out.

Comment: This is on the right track for me, but article talks mainly about static methods and I need to implement instance-based members. can't seem to find any info on instance-based members.

Comment: Missing something
 namespace MyTest
 {
   public class MyGetInfo 
     {
      public string GetInfo()
       { 
          return "Hello, World!";
       } 
      }
 }
 Under Report Properties [Tab] References
    which is [Class Name] and [Instance Name]
 think I tried all combinations but does not build clean